# My C program is stuck in a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop

I am trying to write a program that calculates the triangular number that is provided by the user. When I run it, it gets stuck in the for loop, but will still print out the right answer, because my print statement is outside the loop. Any help is greatly appreciated. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

    //Declare your variables

    int triangle, triNumber, i;


    //Assign values for known variables

    triNumber = 0;


    //Get the user to input the triangular number that they want

    printf("Please enter the triangular number you would like: ");
    scanf("%i\n", &triangle);


    //Execute for loop that will calculate the triangular number

    for (i = 1; i <= triangle; i = i + 1)
    {
        triNumber = triNumber + 1;
    }


    //Display the user's triangular number

    printf("The triangular number is %i\n", triNumber);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you get to see the result, your program did not get stuck in the loop. Q.E.D.

Comment: If it's stuck in the loop and the print is outside the loop, how is it printing the right answer?

Comment: In C do not use loops `i = 1; i <= triangle` but `i = 0; i < triangle`. The form starting from 1 will sooner or later hit you back.

Comment: This does not calculate triangular numbers... It sets `triNumber = triangle`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not stuck in the for loop. You have to change your `scanf()` statement from this:

```
scanf("%i\n", &triangle);
```

to this:

```
scanf("%i", &triangle);
```

Comment: @Rizier123: I'm pretty sure Ctrl+D, Ctrl+Z are not ways to write a newline, those are ways to end the stream.  Very different.